# APP SDK 2.0: Charts in the short term?

Tags: rally

I know you guys will be making a really nice charting tool available for 2.0 SDK soon, but until then, I'd like to use Google Charts.

In the 1.x API, you could could define html object by id, and then use getElementById() to get a reference to that item.  So for example:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

But in the new SDK, you don't have an HTML block to work with-- how would you do the following?  This question is relevant for any item where you want to pin an object to a place in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new API the [app base class](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.App) is simply an extension of Ext.container.Container which itself is an extension of AbstractComponent and so has the [getEl()](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-getEl) method.  (Note that by adding content directly to dom nodes you lose out on the automatic layout functionality provided by Ext containers).

Here's a quick example to illustrate doing something like this though:

```
Ext.define('My.App', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'chartContainer'
        }
    ],
    launch: function() {
        var chartContainer = this.down('#chartContainer').getEl().dom;
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartContainer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Very cool-- where can I find general documentation on this?  I presume this is EXTJS stuff?

Comment: I need to call google.load(), and then call google.setOnLoadCallback(this._drawChart) before I can create a new bar chart, both in the "launch" function.  But it throws an obscure exception before calling _drawChart.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, this is Ext.  All of the Ext source documentation is available alongside the SDK docs here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api

If you provide a source snippet maybe someone can help you debug it...

Answer (score 1):

In the last answer (your code snippet), you were just missing the items child of the app, which creates the chartContainer element you want to render the chart into. I think this code should work for you:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'chartContainer'
        }
    ],

    launch: function() {
        //Write app code here
        google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(this._drawChart);
    },

    _drawChart: function() {
        var chartContainer = this.down('#chartContainer').getEl().dom;
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartContainer);

        var graphArray = [['Module', 'Payload Code', 'Test Code']];

        chartData =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphArray);

        chart.draw(chartData, {width: 700, height: 500});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code.  It crashes with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" inside of "Ext.define.initComponent" initiated from "Ext.define.Rally.loadScripts". Never gets to _drawChart():

I've also added the following line to the rake script to reference the google API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

And here's App.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        //Write app code here
        google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(this._drawChart);
    },

    _drawChart: function() {
        var chartContainer = this.down('#chartContainer').getEl().dom;
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartContainer);

        var graphArray = [['Module', 'Payload Code', 'Test Code']];

        chartData =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphArray);

        chart.draw(chartData, {width: 700, height: 500});
    }
});
```

Comment: Matt seems to have addressed this in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first draft of the SDK 2.0 charting component is now live.

You can find out about it [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.chart.Chart).