# How to add google charts using Rally SDK2.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, sdk, rally

I am hitting my head to wall with this.

[APP SDK 2.0: Charts in the short term?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491663/app-sdk-2-0-charts-in-the-short-term])

I followed above post to add google charts to rally report but ran into problem. I was expecting the answer by ***mattparrish*** in that post to work. but it throws following error:

```
sdk-debug.js:147611 Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined
at constructor._drawChart (App.js?_dc=0.8649522877525893:36)
at constructor.launch (App.js?_dc=0.8649522877525893:30)
at constructor._applyDefaultSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155148)
at constructor.loadSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155054)
at constructor.initComponent (sdk-debug.js:155032)
at constructor (sdk-debug.js:30211)
at constructor.callParent (sdk-debug.js:4469)
at constructor [as _componentConstructor] (sdk-debug.js:34291)
at constructor.callParent (sdk-debug.js:4469)
at constructor (sdk-debug.js:144823)
```

This is how i am adding google jsapi to rally report:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ExtPlusGoogleCharts</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/sdk-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback( Rally.loadScripts(
                [
                      "App.js",
                ],
        function() {
            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"ExtPlusGoogleCharts"
            });
        }, true));

    </script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can we add google charts in rally SDK2.1? If yes, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, is there a special reason you'd like to use google charts? That question you referenced is pretty old and pre-dates the current charting platform in App SDK 2.1, which uses Highcharts.

There's a solid example of how to do this here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/bare-metal-chart

I'm not all that familiar with google charts, so if you'd still like to use those someone else will probably have to post an answer on that.  But hopefully you can use our built-in chart component...

Comment: I am using ur awesome highcharts but I am just curios. I am new to Sencha SDK so I am trying to understand it.